# Create Zip File in Memory from different file paths and Download it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I was trying to create and download a zip file from the different location using `ZipArchive` class.

The files are located in the different file path. I want to create a zip file in c#  in-memory object and then **download it without saving the zip** file in c# / MVC.

I have tried like this:

```
public void DownloadZipFromMultipleFile()
{
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
      {
         archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/appStyle.css"), "myStyle.css");
         archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/NewPath/myScript.js"), "script.js");
      }
   }

   //archive.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

I have successfully added files to `archive` but not able to download the file as a zip file.

Comment: You can direct your memorystream to the response stream. But before that, set the http header of ContentType.

Comment: @PepitoSh Ohh Ok. It is working. Thanks for the response :D

Comment: Can you add your answer here ? @PepitoSh

Comment: I Added these line and now it is working   byte[] bytesInStream = memoryStream.ToArray(); // simpler way of converting to array
                memoryStream.Close();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=name_you_file.zip");
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
                Response.End();

Comment: Oh please add your code as your own answer. I would not take credit for your work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by *PapitoSh* at comment section, I added few lines along with my existing codes and now it is working fine.

```
public void DownloadZipFromMultipleFile()
{
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
      {
         archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/appStyle.css"), "myStyle.css");
         archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/NewPath/myScript.js"), "script.js");
      }

      byte[] bytesInStream = memoryStream.ToArray(); // simpler way of converting to array 
      memoryStream.Close(); 
      Response.Clear(); 
      Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"; 
      Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=name_you_file.zip"); 
      Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream); Response.End();
   }

   //archive.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```